# How to return variable data type?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am writing a macro in Excel that uses a custom function to verify the data type of a field in a form, in order to validate user input later on. The field consists of the study ID, and is a **positive integer** which varies from **1 to n**.

When I enter the number in the field as an Integer (for example, **2**) my function returns **5** (VbDouble), which according to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) is a Double-precision floating-point number.
I tested the field input with **2.0000 and 2**, and both return 5.

The expected result when entering "2" into the field is 2 (Integer).

```vb
Function InputCheck(FieldValue As Variant) As Integer
    Dim TypeCheck As Integer
    TypeCheck = VarType(FieldValue)
    Select Case TypeCheck
    Case 2 'Integer
        InputCheck = 2
    Case 3 'Long integer
        InputCheck = 3
    Case 4 'Single-precision floating-point number
        InputCheck = 4
    Case 5 'Double-precision floating-point number
        InputCheck = 5
    End Select
End Function
```

In my Sub, the code below is supposed to display data type (Integer).

```
If InputCheck(.Cells(iRow, 2).Value) = 2 Then
   MsgBox "Integer"
ElseIf InputCheck(.Cells(iRow, 2).Value) = 3 Then
   MsgBox "Long integer"
ElseIf InputCheck(.Cells(iRow, 2).Value) = 4 Then
   MsgBox "Single-precision floating-point number"
ElseIf InputCheck(.Cells(iRow, 2).Value) = 5 Then
   MsgBox "Double-precision floating-point number"
End If
```

How can I return the data type (**2, Integer**)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686693/is-the-type-of-a-numeric-value-of-a-cell-in-excel-always-considered-as-double You can't really use `VarType` like that against numeric data from a sheet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992958

Comment: Every cell that contains a number in Excel, is holding a `Double`. Cell values are either `Double`, `Date`, `String`, `Boolean`, or `Error`.

Comment: If you want to return "Integer", you need to check if there are decimals and whether the value is under 2^15-1 (max value is halved because there's a sign bit, so the check is between -32767 and 32767)... but that's just saying the value *fits* an Integer data type, not that it *is* one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `VarType` is just going to read what type you defined the variable.
I changed your `as integer` to  `as string` because I think that removes a step, but you can easily go back to old way. You can also add more conditions if you need a more specific answer.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    MsgBox InputCheck(InputBox("Enter Data to test", "DataTypeTest", "")), vbOKOnly, "DataTypeTest"
End Sub

Function InputCheck(FieldValue) As String
    If IsNumeric(FieldValue) Then
        If CDbl(FieldValue) = Round(FieldValue, 0) Then
            InputCheck = "Integer" '(Or long or whatever...)
            Exit Function
        Else
            InputCheck = "Decimal" '(or double.. or whatever you want to call it)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Else
        If IsDate(FieldValue) Then
            InputCheck = "Date"
            Exit Function
        Else
            InputCheck = "String"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Test with msgbox sub.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain what the -- in front of FieldValue signifies please? Or is that a typo. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm forcing whatever the value is to be treated as a value. I'm told it's very bad practice, but I've never personally had problems with it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Your code works as intended for my purposes!

Comment: Good stuff, let me know if you run into any problems. Accept or upvote the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Curious what else the value could possibly be treated as given it's passing an `IsNumeric` test... Feels like a surrogate for an explicit `Val` function call, although an explicit `CDbl` conversion would probably be better.

Comment: You know, I'm not sure exactly, but it didn't work properly without it, and worked correctly with it. I tested `CDbl()` and that works great... and I think it's more *"correct"* ... so I've updated the above code, changing `If --FieldValue = Roun...` to  `If CDbl(FieldValue) = Roun...` . Cheers!